# CSS - How to get buttons of different heights aligned properly?

Tags: css

I'm building a JavaScript calculator, and I have been having problems getting all of the buttons aligned properly. I made my equals button bigger than the rest, and it's throwing off the alignment of the bottom two rows because of this. I have tried using `vertical-align`, `float` and `display: inline` but can't seem to get the right combination to make it work. Can someone steer me in the right direction here?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ojcmdn9/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove position absolute from the equals button, and set the last row to position absolute: https://jsfiddle.net/jdqem3hh/2/

```
* {
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-size: 25px;
}
body {
  background-color: #202020;
  font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
}
#output {
  background: #94AFB5;
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.calculator {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 410px;
  height: 520px;
  padding: 2px;
  background: #5591C3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
button {
  margin: 2px;
  width: 85px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #084D87;
  color: #D17900;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #053C6A;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
} 
button:active {
  background-color: #084D87;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #053C6A;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
#zero {
  width: 181px;
}
#ac, #ce {
  background-color: #EC0000;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #BC0000;
}
.last-row {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
  left: 31px;
}
#equals {
  height: 125px;
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the smaller buttons inside transparent float div with the same height as the big buttons in line.

Comment: Hello @Kalin , welcome to SO. Glad that you are trying to help the community by answering questions. However, this answer needs improvement. You should be adding code to your answer / create a JSFiddle link and / or provide helpful links. Cheers!